# Problem with superscript

Tags: string-manipulation, options, variable, assignment, subscript

1. I would like to know if there is option to make such scrpits like in this picture below.
2. Is option to put letter instead of a *?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the first one:

```
Row[{Superscript[" ", "*"], M}]
```

and the second by

```
Superscript[M, "*"]
```

and if you want the equals sign at the end:

```
Row[{Superscript[M, "*"], "="}]
```

You can replace the * with anything you wish.

Comment: `\[InvisibleSpace]` is probably better for the first one.

Comment: Thanks you but is option to assign *M to function?

Comment: No, you can't assign *M to a function. All variable and function names start with letters, and by convention, should be small (not capital). You asked for "scripts" which I interpreted as text (because it makes sense), not variables (which do not).

Comment: @Papa you would need to use `Symbolize` from the Notations package if you want to make M* a symbol.